# CSS3 - menu element behind its parent?

Tags: menu, css

Like in the title.

I have three level menu and want it to look like:

```
[ FIRST LEVEL ITEM ]
--------------------
[ SECOND LEVEL ITEM ]
[ SECOND LEVEL ITEM ]
[ THIRD LEVEL ITEM ]
[ SECOND LEVEL ITEM ]
[ THIRD LEVEL ITEM ]
[ SECOND LEVEL ITEM ]
```

But third level items are displaying just behind the other items.

I added huge 50px red frame to them, so you will be able to see what's the point:

http://jsfiddle.net/TQH9v/

I'm a bit sleepy and tired & have to finish this code today, so sorry for so many stupid questions. At least easy reputation points :P

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS has a lot of superfluous stuff in it so I'm not going to edit it exactly.

What you need to learn about is the wonderful z-index model. You never mentioned if you wanted this to work in IE, so I will just explain it for real browsers.

First, add `position: relative;` for all LI elements. Something like

```
#page-navigation li { position: relative; }
```

will work.

Now, add a z-index to each UL element that contains a "popup" menu and set it to a z-index that is higher than the parent LI. If you do not set the z-index, it will default to 0.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/understanding_css_z-index

If you want this to work in IE, you must set the parent LI to a higher z-index than it's contained popout UL. This is just how stupid IE works. http://brenelz.com/blog/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/

Comment: Actually it doesn't work my friend, I know the code is a bit chaotic, I'm working on it at the moment, but the main question in this case is HOW TO free some space for 3rd level ul, because even with z-indexes and relative positions they're just ABOVE the other links :) And I don't wnat them above, but below :)

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out, had to change links height to automatic, so they free space for children. Anyways +1 for you as you're the first and the last person who at least tried to help me.

Comment: Oh.. in your original question you said it was "below", which I thought meant it in the z-index model since that was the most glaring problem.